# Flights to Georgia from Western Europe

Tags: air-travel, georgia-country, western-europe

What are my options for travelling from Western European cities to Tbilisi, Georgia by air?

Comment: Which western cities? That's a huge range of hundreds of cities...

Comment: @MarkMayo have you looked into flights to Tbilisi. Not everywhere does them and they change quite often.

Comment: @AndrewWelch There are few direct flights but you can connect to fly to Tbilisi through Istanbul for example which basically will cover all of Western Europe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Wikipedia page for the [Tbilisi airport](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tbilisi_International_Airport) lists the airlines with flights to Tbilisi. Looks like your best Western Europe options are Rome, Amsterdam, Paris (seasonal) and Munich. There are other flights from Eastern Europe.

If you're looking to get in cheap, Wizz Air (a discount airline) serves [Kutaisi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kutaisi_International_Airport) from various locations in Eastern Europe.

Comment: Perfect answer, thanks very much. This is very useful.